# Does pointwise convergence imply bounded variation?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, bounded-variation

**Problem**: Let $\{f_k\} \in BV([a,b])$ and $f_k \rightarrow f$ pointwise in $[a,b]$. Suppose $V(f_k;a,b) \le M$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ for some $M \in (0,\infty)$. Is it enough for a pointwise convergence to make $f$ be of bounded variation. Prove or disprove.

**Comments**: As far as I understood, this problem is the same as the ones in [link1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2329212/uniform-convergence-and-bounded-variation-functions) and [link2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3419698/pointwise-convergent-sequence-of-bounded-variation-functions). However, the accepted answers in these links differ, as [link1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2329212/uniform-convergence-and-bounded-variation-functions) proves the statement, [link2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3419698/pointwise-convergent-sequence-of-bounded-variation-functions) disproves it. In the last part of the accepted answer in [link2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3419698/pointwise-convergent-sequence-of-bounded-variation-functions), authors states:

> Each $f_n$ is of bounded variation because it is decresing and bounded on $(0,1]$.

Which I think is not correct as we are working on closed interval $[a,b]$, not $(a,b]$. So, is it indeed enough for a pointwise convergence to make $f$ be of bounded variation?

Comment: They are different: the first link requires uniform boundness of variation (variation of each $f_n$ is at most $K$), the second doesn't. Your question is exactly the same as the first, with replacement $K$ for $M$. For the reasoning - boundness and monotonicy is enough even on $(0, 1]$ - just say that $f(0) = \sup_{x\in (0, 1]} f(x)$, and you get bounded monotonic function on $[0, 1]$, thus with bounded variation, and original $f$ is restriction of it.

Comment: @mihaild you mean my question is exactly the same as the second one, right?

Comment: Depends on how to read "for all $k$ for some $M$" in your question. I assumed it is $\exists M \forall k$ (there is one $M$ that works for any $k$), and then it is the first one. If it is $\forall k \exists M$ ($M$ depends on $k$) then it is the second.

Comment: @mihaild Now I see the difference. Yes, I think in my question it is $\exists M \forall k$, thus making it the same as the first one. Thank you for the clarification.